# Cannot modify $stateParam parameter in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am redirecting into a state using `$state.go('someState', {'param':true})`and as you can see I am also modifying a flag as it happens.

However when I try to switch the flag back to false via `$stateParams.param = false;` in the state's controller, nothing seems to be happening and the flag remains `true`

Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

This is where the redirection is happening

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $state) {

   $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
     ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
       if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) navigator.splashscreen.hide();
     });
   });

   this.reset = function() {
     $state.go('register', {
       'reset': true
     });
   }
});
```

This is where the attempt to change the flag is made

```
app.controller("OtherController", function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {

   $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
      var reset = $stateParams.reset;
      if (reset) {              
        $stateParams.reset = false;
        alert("After resetting, set flag back to false: " + $stateParams.reset);    
      }
   });

});
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

This is how my state for the `OtherController` is set up in my app config. Note that I have no state set up for `MainController` however I am obviously still specifying it in `index.html`. I am also specifying `OtherController` in its respective template file `register.html`.

```
$stateProvider
.state('register', {
  url: '/register',
  params: {
    'reset': false
  },
  templateUrl: 'templates/register.html'
})
```

Comment: Where do you do this $stateParams.param = false;?

Comment: Please check the edit!

Comment: did you check whether it is hitting or not '$ionicView.beforeEnter' ?

Comment: Yes indeed it is, had a few alerts set up to confirm this.

Comment: Could you please add your routing config

Comment: Okay I have added the config for `OtherController`

Answer (score 0):

Mayby you can do in this way. Use event $stateChangeStart instead of $ionicView.beforeEnter

```
 $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)        {  
     var reset = toP.reset;
     if (reset) {              
        toP.reset = false;
        alert("After resetting, set flag back to false: " + toP.reset);    
     }
```

});

Comment: Tried using both `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` events but the flag just won't seem to budge. I simply need to access the parameter again and change it back to `false` once redirection happens.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/D9r41sEn1QTDjaYkDHtA?p=preview 
Here I pass a param with a value in go function and in stateChangeStart I change this value with another one and in the final view I see the value changed

Answer (score -2):

are you injecting `$stateParams` in your controller like below?

```
controller('testCrtl',
    [       '$scope','$stateParams'
    function($scope , $stateParams ) {
....
....
}
```

Edit.............

Did you miss routing ? If Yes then....
You need to implement routing like this

```
$stateProvider.state('toState', {
  templateUrl:'test.html',
  controller:'stateController',
  params: {
    'reset': true, 
  }
});
```

Then you can navigate to it like so:

```
$state.go('register', {
       'reset': true
     }
```

Comment: Why should I specify a boolean value as a string?

Comment: I see. Yes of course I set it up in my app config as shown in my latest edit. Please check!